# GAP semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, gap, semidirect-product

I am newbie in the GAP and in the group theory. Now I am trying to make semidirect product if GL(3,2) and GL(3,2) inversed and transposed. I use code below

```
H:=GeneralLinearGroup(3, 2);
GH:=GeneratorsOfGroup(H);
GT:=List(GH, g->Inverse(TransposedMat(g)));
T:=Group(GT);
A:=AutomorphismGroup(T);
elts := Elements(A); 

map:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(H, A,GeneratorsOfGroup(H), [elts[2], elts[10]]);  
SemidirectProduct(T,map,H);
```

I got error about "GroupHomomorphismByImages" failed. I have no idea what should I do. 
From related topics I got that I should define proper homomorphism. But I cannot imagine what is possible here.

I will be very thankful if you help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I'm guessing [this chapter](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap12.html) of the manual is relevant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the GAP forums.

Comment: @Shaun. The chapter you link to is not really relevant here. The issue is with the `SemidirectProduct` operation ( https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap49.html#X87FE512E7DB7346C ) and the concept of mapping generators to homomorphic images, not just arbitrary elements.

Comment: Thank you, @ahulpke. Sorry, Зиля Хуснутдинова.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GAP tests that the map you give indeed is a homomorphism. Why should the generators of $H$ be mapped to (particularly) elements 2 and 1.

What you want is to find the elements corresponding to the chosen generators of $H$, that is the inner automorphisms induced by the inverse transposed matrices:

```
gap> imgs:=List(GT,x->InnerAutomorphism(T,x));
[ ^<an immutable 3x3 matrix over GF2>, ^<an immutable 3x3 matrix over GF2> ]
gap> map:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(H, A, GeneratorsOfGroup(H),imgs);
CompositionMapping( [ (5,7)(6,8), (2,3,5)(4,7,6) ] ->
[ ^<an immutable 3x3 matrix over GF2>, ^<an immutable 3x3 matrix over GF2> ],
 <action isomorphism> )
gap> SemidirectProduct(T,map,H);
Group([ (11,13)(12,14), (8,9,11)(10,13,12), (2,6)(3,7)(11,13)(12,14), (1,2,4)(3,6,5)(8,9,11)(10,13,12) ])
```

You could also check for the correct index numbers in this particular case (but for different groups they will be different):

```
gap> List(imgs,x->Position(elts,x));
[ 24, 105 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, @ahulpke